# Error allocating string in YACC

Tags: c, malloc, yacc

I have this Yacc code:

```
...
%union{
    int counter;
    char* partial_code;
}
....
single_selection_predicate: STRING EQ SINGLE_QUOTATION STRING SINGLE_QUOTATION 
        {   $<counter>$ = 1;
            printf("Counter: %d\n", $<counter>$);
            int size = sizeof(char)*(strlen($<partial_code>1) + strlen($<partial_code>4) + 7);
            $<partial_code>$ = (char*)malloc(size);
            printf("Counter: %d\n", $<counter>$);}
        ;
....
```

I would expect the first and the second printf in the syntax rule related code block to print the same output. But, I get something like this:

```
Counter: 1
Counter: 7402224
```

Maybe some overflow is occurring, but I cannot figure out why. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unions are not structs.

In your union, `counter` and `partial_code` occupy the same memory location.
Your write to `partial_code` overwrites the assignment to `counter`.

```
%union{
    int counter;
    char* partial_code;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Charlie's answer, you can easily stick a struct into the union:

```
%union{
    struct {
        int counter;
        char* partial_code;
    } code_and_counter;
    char *partial_code;
}
%token<partial_code> STRING
%type<code_and_counter> single_selection_predicate
%%
single_selection_predicate: STRING EQ SINGLE_QUOTATION STRING SINGLE_QUOTATION 
    {   $$.counter = 1;
        printf("Counter: %d\n", $$.counter);
        int size = strlen($1) + strlen($4) + 7;
        $$.partial_code = malloc(size);
        printf("Counter: %d\n", $$.counter);}
    ;
```

In addition, you should rarely if ever use the `$<tag>X` syntax -- you should ALWAYS declare the type of the token/non-terminal as shown above and let yacc stick the tag into the action code for you.

In addition, NEVER use `sizeof(char)` (it's always 1), and never explicitly cast the result of malloc.